# How to deal with multiple variants of application using same Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

We were wondering how to parameterize the building process. We have an application that can have features if the right libraries are there at compile time. Also, we optionally would like to include some other debugging applications into the same image.

Our current strategy is to comment-in/out lines in the Dockerfile and compile it to another name.

```
# Dockerfile in multiple variants / t-shirt sizing:
# - as is, with all the #something; comments: very basic compilation without features
# - removing #something; enable a variant/feature

# see build and test instructions below

###
# REQUIRED: INSTALL COMPILER, DOWNLOAD AND INSTALL BITS AND PIECES
###
# start from a fedora 28 image
FROM    fedora:28 AS compiler_build
RUN     echo "############################# COMPILER IMAGE #################################"

# install requirements
#RUN     dnf upgrade -y && dnf clean all
RUN     dnf install -y git gcc gcc-c++ make automake autoconf gettext-devel

#######
#  OPTIONAL: CAM SUPPORT 
#######
#cam;RUN     dnf install -y wget mercurial patch glibc-static
#cam;
#cam;# do not use pre-built dvb-apps and libdvbcsa from distro-mirror, but build from sources. This is required for cam support on fedora.
#cam;RUN     cd /usr/local/src && \
#cam;        hg clone http://linuxtv.org/hg/dvb-apps && \
#cam;        cd dvb-apps && \
#cam;        # patching for >=4.14 Kernel (https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/linuxtv-dvb-apps)
#cam;        wget -q -O - https://git.busybox.net/buildroot/plain/package/dvb-apps/0003-handle-static-shared-only-build.patch | patch -p1 && \
#cam;        wget -q -O - https://git.busybox.net/buildroot/plain/package/dvb-apps/0005-utils-fix-build-with-kernel-headers-4.14.patch | patch -p1 && \
#cam;        wget -q -O - https://gitweb.gentoo.org/repo/gentoo.git/plain/media-tv/linuxtv-dvb-apps/files/linuxtv-dvb-apps-1.1.1.20100223-perl526.patch | patch -p1 && \
#cam;        make && make install && \
#cam;        ldconfig   # b/c libdvben50221.so

#######
# OPTIONAL: SCAM SUPPORT 
#######
#scam;RUN     yum install -y openssl-devel dialog svn pcsc-lite pcsc-lite-devel libusb libusb-devel findutils file libtool
#scam;
#scam;RUN     cd /usr/local/src && \
#scam;        git clone https://code.videolan.org/videolan/libdvbcsa.git && \
#scam;        cd libdvbcsa && \
#scam;        autoreconf -i -f && \
#scam;        ./configure --prefix=/usr && make && make install && \
#scam;        ldconfig   # b/c libdvbcsa.so
#scam;        #dnf install -y https://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/fedora/rpmfusion-free-release-$(rpm -E %fedora).noarch.rpm https://download1.rpmfusion.org/nonfree/fedora/rpmfusion-nonfree-release-$(rpm -E %fedora).noarch.rpm && \
#scam;        #dnf install -y libdvbcsa-devel
#scam;
#scam;RUN     cd /usr/local/src && \
#scam;        svn checkout http://www.streamboard.tv/svn/oscam/trunk oscam-svn && \
#scam;        cd oscam-svn && \
#scam;        make USE_PCSC=1 USE_LIBUSB=1
#scam;         
#scam;RUN     cd /usr/local/src && \
#scam;        git clone https://github.com/gfto/tsdecrypt.git && \
#scam;        cd tsdecrypt && \
#scam;        git submodule init && \
#scam;        git submodule update && \
#scam;        make && make install    

#######  
# REQUIRED: ACTUAL APPLICATION ITSELF
#######
# note: the ./configure will detect cam/scam support automagically if everything provided
RUN     cd /usr/local/src && \
        ldconfig && \
        git clone https://github.com/braice/MuMuDVB.git && \
        cd MuMuDVB && \
        autoreconf -i -f && \
        ./configure --enable-android && \
        make && make install

#######
# OPTIONAL: TOOLBOXING
####### 
#tool;RUN     cd /usr/local/src && \
#tool;        git clone git://git.videolan.org/bitstream.git && \
#tool;        cd bitstream && \
#tool;        make all && make install
#tool;
#tool;RUN     cd /usr/local/src && \
#tool;        dnf install -y libev-devel && \
#tool;        git clone https://code.videolan.org/videolan/dvblast.git && \
#tool;        cd dvblast && \
#tool;        make all && make install
#tool;         
#tool;RUN     cd /usr/local/src && \
#tool;        yum install -y wget bzip2 && \
#tool;        wget http://wirbel.htpc-forum.de/w_scan/w_scan-20170107.tar.bz2 && \
#tool;        tar -jxf w_scan-20170107.tar.bz2 && \
#tool;        cd w_scan-20170107/ && \
#tool;        ./configure && make && make install
#tool;          
#tool;RUN     cd /usr/local/src && \
#tool;        git clone https://github.com/stefantalpalaru/w_scan2.git && \
#tool;        cd w_scan2 && \
#tool;        autoreconf -i -f && \
#tool;        ./configure && make && make install
#tool;         
#tool;RUN     cd /usr/local/src && \
#tool;      yum install -y wget && \
#tool;        wget http://udpxy.com/download/udpxy/udpxy-src.tar.gz && \
#tool;        tar -zxf udpxy-src.tar.gz && \
#tool;        cd udpxy-*/ && \
#tool;        make && make install 
#tool;          
#tool;RUN     cd /usr/local/src && \
#tool;        yum install -y xz wget && \
#tool;        wget ftp://ftp.videolan.org/pub/videolan/miniSAPserver/0.3.8/minisapserver-0.3.8.tar.xz && \
#tool;        tar -Jxf minisapserver-0.3.8.tar.xz && \
#tool;        cd minisapserver-*/ && \
#tool;        ./configure && make && make install
#tool;
#tool;RUN     cd /usr/local/src && \
#tool;        yum install -y wget && \
#tool;        wget https://dl.bintray.com/tvheadend/fedora/bintray-tvheadend-fedora-4.2-stable.repo

###
# OPTIONAL: START OVER AND ONLY RE-INSTALL
###
FROM    fedora:28
RUN     echo "############################# RUNTIME IMAGE #################################"

# copy the whole /usr/local from the previous compiler-image (note the --from)
COPY    --from=compiler_build /usr/local /usr/local

# install runtime libraries
#scam;RUN     dnf install -y openssl-devel pcsc-lite libusb
#tool;RUN     dnf install -y v4l-utils libev
#tool;RUN     mv /usr/local/src/bintray-tvheadend-fedora-4.2-stable.repo /etc/yum.repos.d
#tool;RUN     dnf search tvheadend # experimental


# unfortunately, some make's need gcc anyway :(
RUN     dnf install -y make gcc gcc-c++ cpp glibc-devel glibc-headers kernel-headers

# re-install all the stuff from before
RUN     test -e /usr/local/src/dvb-apps && cd /usr/local/src/dvb-apps && make install && ldconfig || exit 0
RUN     test -e /usr/local/src/libdvbcsa && cd /usr/local/src/libdvbcsa && make install && ldconfig || exit 0
RUN     cd /usr/local/src/MuMuDVB && make install && mumudvb -v
RUN     test -e /usr/local/src/tsdecrypt && cd /usr/local/src/tsdecrypt && make install || exit 0
RUN     test -e /usr/local/src/bitstream && cd /usr/local/src/bitstream && make install || exit 0
RUN     test -e /usr/local/src/dvblast && cd /usr/local/src/dvblast && make install || exit 0
RUN     test -e /usr/local/src/w_scan-20170107 && cd /usr/local/src/w_scan-20170107 && make install || exit 0
RUN     test -e /usr/local/src/w_scan2 && cd /usr/local/src/w_scan2 && make install || exit 0
RUN     test -e /usr/local/src/udpxy-*/ && cd /usr/local/src/udpxy-*/ && make install || exit 0
RUN     test -e /usr/local/src/minisapserver-*/ && cd /usr/local/src/minisapserver-*/ && make install || exit 0

# remove gcc again
RUN     dnf remove -y make gcc gcc-c++ cpp glibc-devel glibc-headers kernel-headers

RUN     echo "############################# FINAL STEPS #################################"

# add a runtime user
RUN     useradd -c "simple user" -g users -G audio,video,cdrom,dialout,lp,tty,games user

# include this very file into the image
COPY    Dockerfile /

# use this user as default user
USER    user

# assume persistent storage
VOLUME  /tmp

# assume exposed ports
EXPOSE  8500:8500

# assume standard runtime executable
CMD     ["/bin/bash"]

###
# RECOMMENDED: HOW TO BUILD AND TEST
###

# build mumudvb plain:
#     cat Dockerfile.template > Dockerfile;                              time docker build -t my_mumudvb_simple .
# enable cam/scam support:
#     sed -r 's_^#(cam|scam);__g' Dockerfile.template > Dockerfile;      time docker build -t my_mumudvb_cam .
# enable tool but not scam support:
#     sed -r 's_^#(tool);__g' Dockerfile.template > Dockerfile;          time docker build -t my_mumudvb_tool .
# enable all support:
#     sed -r 's_^#(cam|scam|tool);__g' Dockerfile.template > Dockerfile; time docker build -t my_mumudvb_full .

# simpe compare and test
# $ docker run -it --rm my_mumudvb_simple /bin/bash
# $ docker run -it --rm my_mumudvb_full /usr/local/bin/w_scan
# $ docker run -it --rm my_mumudvb_cam /usr/local/bin/mumudvb
# $ docker run -it --rm my_mumudvb_tool /usr/local/bin/mumudvb

# run a scan. note the mapped device tree /dev/dvb
# $ docker run -it --rm --device /dev/dvb/ my_mumudvb_full w_scan -f s -s S13E0 -D1c

# run a mumudvb instance. Note the mapped device, filesystem and tcp-port
# $ docker run -it --rm --device /dev/dvb/ --volume ${PWD}/conf:/conf -p 8500:8500 my_mumudvb_cam mumudvb -d -c /conf/test.conf
```

What can you recommend how to implement and manage this? Re-using the compile-intermediate images could save some space and time, using tags could easy the variant-usage, etc.

What would you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Are the permutations hierarchical in any fashion? If so, you could create intermediate images and inherit from them. This will have the advantage that the "ancestor" part of the builds will be pre-built, and will not need further build time (except when they change, of course).

If not, you could use your favourite scripting language to build your Dockerfiles. It does not really matter how you do this, what matters is that you automate it. I would suggest using an array to specify, for each named build, what sections it should include. Since this will run quickly, you could always assemble all Dockerfiles, and make that something you do when you do the image builds themselves, so that your specification for a Dockerfile does not come out of sync with the Dockerfiles themselves.

In fact, if you do this, it may be worth *not* committing your Dockerfiles to version control, since that is one less thing to come out of sync with your scripted definitions.

### Addendum

Regarding this remark:

> We optionally would like to include some other debugging applications into the same image.

It's worth being careful here about what constitutes a tested image. If you add optional debug tools into an image, then:

- if this is not to be deployed to production, then you may end up testing against a version of your app that is not in production. The ideal is to use the same image all the way through your development workflow.
- if this is to be deployed to production, it's worth considering whether the attack surface may be increased.

Comment: We've been down that road as well, there are numerous ways how to achieve this using any scripting. Avoiding any further building-steps that an autonomous building system might not understand, we maybe missed a nice feature of docker that addresses this. Looking for recommendations and tips.
(Yes, mumudvb compilation is different if dvb-apps and libdvbcsa were compiled/installed or not, so last ancestor is quite early)

Comment: Well, I'd argue that the devops approach is (mostly) to get it done quickly in a way that is easy, and improve iteratively when tools and knowledge allow. I don't _think_ the Dockerfile allows for conditional sections. In any case, I'd be happy to take my advice above if I had a need for this.

Comment: Depends, you'll also be very quick with introducing obstacles, especially if your additional steps involve a lot of logic. I don't want to translate pages of win32 cmd scripts anymore, and i don't want to leave any scripted-up mess behind if there is an parametric way to solve the same.
Thanks for the hint about about conditionals, Dockerfile itself don't, but the RUN statements do...

Comment: I am not familiar with any built-in Docker technique to do that; maybe someone will add an answer with a fresh idea. I've added an update about putting debugging tools into live too.

Answer (score 0):

Look at using ARG and ENV in your Dockerfile. ARG sets values that are available while the image is being built. ENV sets variables available and persist with the image after it is built.

For example, say you needed different settings files based on DEV or PRD versions, you might do this:

```
ARG=settings_filename
ENV=settings_filename=${settings_filename}
```

Then call docker to build the image like so:

```
docker build --build-arg settings_filename="settings.dev"
```

The ARG line in the Dockerfile sets the value to "settings.dev", but ARG values are not persisted to the image. The ENV line actually persists whatever the ARG value is as an environment variable in the image that is produced.